# install missing node libraries on shared hosting

Tags: node.js

I am trying to install node js on a shared hosting provider. I followed steps mentioned at https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts#Installation-prerequisites and installed the latest version.

However, I ran node --version and got the following errors.

I am a little out of my depth here...I have no idea how to resolve these errors.

```
prompt [/lib64]# node --version
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.10' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.3' not found (required by node)
node: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by node)
prompt [/lib64]#
```

We can have a subdiscussion on why i am installing it on a shared hosting but help resolving these errors would be awesome.

Comment: Maybe try to install a more recent version of node to see if the problem persists.

Comment: It is the latest version